# Ruby on Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new in ruby on rails. I was trying to check some code. I copied all folders of an existing project from my friends and pasted them to a newly created project at my machine. And also changed the config file. It shows following error:

*Template is missing
Missing template movies/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "../Software Engineering for Software as a Service/Software/Project/rottenpotatoes/app/views"*

Some one suggested me that it is because haml is not installed, i installed haml by "gem install haml" but it still shows the same message. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

If rails had access to the HAML gem it would show HAML as a handler in that error. Your error does not. It's possible you need to restart your rails server.

You should be using the Gemfile for managing gems, though. Add `gem 'haml'` to your Gemfile. Go to your console and cd to the application directory. Run bundler to install the gems with the `bundle` command. Restart your rails server.

Comment: Hmm.. I have the exact same issue, but have restarted the server, and the Gemfile definitely contains 'haml' and it shows up when running bundle.  How does one determine "If rails had access to the HAML gem"?